# Use Flags Enum space like an integer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums, bitwise-operators

Can i use the space, between the Flags of an Enum for storing integers? I just tried this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Occupation : int
{
    Open=16,
    Flagged = 32,
    Bomb = 64 
}
```

In my expectation that should lead to an enum like this:

```
0b0 ... 0
0b1 ... 1
0b10 ... 2
.
.
0b1111 ... 15
0b10000 ... Open
0b10001 ... Open + 1
0b10010 ... Open + 2
.
.
0b011111 ... Open + 15
0b100000 ... Flagged
0b100001 ... Flagged + 1
.
0b101111 ... Flagged + 15
0b110000 ... Flagged, Open
0b110001 ... Flagged, Open + 1
```

and so on. I've hoped, the Enum will just ignore the values between the flags, but it seems like they are all set to 0 (or None) if I bit-AND the Enum like this:

```
Occupation occ = Occupation.Open; //initialize the enum with a Flag
occ += 8; //add 8 to the first bits of the enum without touching the Flags
Console.WriteLine((occ & (Occupation) 8 ).ToString());
//Expected Output: 8
//Actual Output: 0
```

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) it should be possible to "store some values" in there (at least if you cast it from an integer). Do i really have to cast it from an integer everywhere, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: unclear. any int value is valid, just not every value is named. you are occupying bits of the underlying type, not "ints".

Comment: Shouldn't you use | instead of &? as in `Console.WriteLine((occupation | (Occupation)8).ToString());`

Comment: do you mean that when you start with 16, the first four bits are available to store a value ranging from 0..15? yes they are, but you still need to mask the higher bytes away if intend to use the "named bits range" at the same time. anyway this is confusing and maybe an XY problem.

Comment: I just found the answer ... i have to use 7 and not 8. because 7 is 0b111. Now i can extract the bits with `Console.WriteLine((occupation & (Occupation)7).ToString;` I could also use 15 if i want to store a maxValue of 15; Thanks a lot. Should i delete or close this question?

Comment: A good question contains an mcve ([mcve]) and samples with expected an actual results. It is not clear what your problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

As [dlatikay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1132334/dlatikay) mentioned in the comments, it is indeed possible to store an integer in front of the Flags in the enum. I just used the wrong integer to extract the number. Because the flags are always powers of 2, the Number for the extraction must be one smaller then the first Flag. In this example the first Flag is 16. So you can store numbers up to 15 in this enum and also use 15 for the extraction.

*Example:*

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    FlagA = 16,          //0b010000
    FlagB = 32,          //0b100000
}

.
.

MyEnum e = MyEnum.FlagA; //0b010000
e += 6;                  //0b010000 + 0b000110 EQUALS 0b010110
int x = (int)e & 15      //15=0b001111 AND e=0b010110 EQUALS 0b000110
Console.Write(x);        //6
Console.WriteLine(e.HasFlag(MyEnum.A)); //true
```